# CSS padding-bottom does not seem to work

Tags: html, css, padding, footer

I need to put space between the fixed footer and the bottom of the page. I've tried setting a padding for `#main-content`, but it's not working. Is there a problem here that I failed to see?

[image]

**CSS**

```
#main-content {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left:20px; 
    padding-right:20px;
    height: 300px; 

    box-sizing:border-box;
    padding-top: 50px; 
    padding-bottom: 200px;    
}

footer {
    background-color: #00496b;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    position: fixed;
}
```

Instead of getting the desired result, the main contents disappear behind the footer, instead. I want the `#main-content` to go a little further up. Hope I have explained the problem enough.

Comment: send me the url?

Comment: The site is not up as yet... Am I assuming correctly that the code looks ok.

Comment: Just put up pic of the problem. Obviously I have attempted changing padding-bottom: 200px; to many different values. (no difference)

Comment: try setting a margin instead of padding

Comment: Please include the HTML code, so we can debug this better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this CSS code:

```
#main-content {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left:20px; 
    padding-right:20px;
    height: 300px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    padding-top: 50px; 
    padding-bottom: 200px;    
}
```

you have set a fixed height for **#main-content** due to which the **padding-bottom** is not effective. Remove `height: 300px;` property or just replace **300px** with **auto**.

The CSS code should look like this:

```
#main-content {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left:20px; 
    padding-right:20px;
    height: auto;  //height is set to auto
    box-sizing:border-box;
    padding-top: 50px; 
    padding-bottom: 200px;    
}
```

Now, the **padding-bottom** property should work. Let me know it this helps :)

Comment: That was it.. 5 Stars... Thanks so much.

Comment: Glad i could help :)

Comment: height change from fixed value to auto will change element behavior

Answer (score 0):

Try `margin-bottom` instead of `padding-bottom`

Answer (score -1):

Footer has bottom zero and keep footer to bottom. When you type one more div between you see that padding-bottom work properly. Try padding-bottom: 500px;  and change to padding-bottom: 20px; that you see changes because #main-content is very height, 300px. I type border and now you can see that padding-bottom works normal:

```
    <style>
#main-content {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left:20px; 
    padding-right:20px;
    height: 100px; 

    box-sizing:border-box;
    padding-top: 50px; 
    padding-bottom: 200px; 
    border: 1px solid blue;   


}
footer {
            background-color: #00496b;
            width: 100%;
            bottom: 0;
            position: fixed;
        }
</style>
<div id="main-content">
lkdjad d,a dma dm dmad mad ad,ma dma dma dmad a 
</div>
<div>
midle midle
</div>
<footer>
footer footer footerfooter footer footerfooter footer footerfooter footer footerfooter footer footerfooter footer footerfooter footer footerfooter footer footerfooter footer footerfooter footer footerfooter footer footerfooter footer footerfooter footer footerfooter footer footerfooter footer footerfooter footer footerfooter footer footerfooter footer footerfooter footer footerfooter footer footerfooter footer footerfooter footer footerfooter footer footerfooter footer footerfooter footer footerfooter footer footerfooter footer footerfooter footer footerfooter footer footerfooter footer footerfooter footer footerfooter footer footerfooter footer footerfooter footer footerfooter footer footerfooter footer footerfooter footer footerfooter footer footerfooter footer footerfooter footer footerfooter footer footerfooter footer footerfooter footer footerfooter footer footerfooter footer footerfooter footer footerfooter footer footerfooter footer footerfooter footer footerfooter footer footerfooter footer footerfooter footer footerfooter footer footerfooter footer footerfooter footer footerfooter footer footerfooter footer footerfooter footer footerfooter footer footerfooter footer footerfooter footer footerfooter footer footerfooter footer footerfooter footer footerfooter footer footerfooter footer footerfooter footer footerfooter footer footerfooter footer footerfooter footer footer
</footer>
```

Comment: Thanks for this - but still the same result. As I said previously it makes little difference what value I place in padding-bottom:

Comment: I type border and now you can see that padding-bottom works normal. Copy my code and change value of padding-bottom and you see all is ok.

Answer (score -1):

```
padding: 250px; 
margin-bottom: 250px;
```

use both

Comment: Please explain your answer. Don't just dump code and expect everyone to understand it.